# Analytic continution of a real analytic funtion of two variables

Tags: analytic-continuation

The process of the continuation of the analytic function of one complex variable along the boundary is well known. If two complex analytic functions, defined in complex domains can be continuously extended to the common boundary, then they generate an analytic function on the union of these domains.

I want to know, is "the same" is true for real analytic functions of two variables? It seems to me that it is true, but I cannot prove it. Does anyone know if this is true and if so where it is proven?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question right, but $x^2+y^2$ and $1/(x^2+y^2)$ agree on the unit circle.

Comment: You understood my question correctly! Thanks for the example.